# Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region and let $h,g$ meromorphic functions in $U$. If $h$ has an essential singularity in $U$. Can I say that $h=g$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region and let $h,g$ meromorphic functions in $U$. Suppose that there exist a set $W\subseteq U$ with a acumulation point in $U$ with $h(w)=g(w)$ for all $w\in W$.

**If $h$ has an essential singularity in $U$. Can I say that $h=g$?**

**Remark:** 
The case that $h$ has no essential singularities was solved in the comments of the post:['Identity theorem' for Meromorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905376/identity-theorem-for-meromorphic-functions#comment3629865_905376).

Therefore,   I think that the important question is what happens if $W$ has the  limit point in an essential singularity of $h$ in $U$.

Comment: meromorphic on $U$ functions don't have any essential singularities on $U$, so maybe you mean an essential singularity on $\partial U$ ?

Comment: and a counter-example is $g(z) = 0, h(z)= \sin(1/z)$ on $Re(z) > 0$, which are equal whenever $\sin(1/z)= 0$ i.e. $1/z = k \pi$, $z = \frac{1}{k \pi}$, so $W = \{\frac{1}{k\pi} \ \mid \  k \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$ works. of course if $W$ contains  a non-empty open (or even a curve), then clearly $g= h$ on this open and hence on $U$. (and replacing open by $C^1$ curve also works)

Comment: @user1952009 If the essential singularity is not an accumulation point, then we can say $f = g$?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca : ??

Comment: I think that everything is answered, see the linked discussion for the sufficient conditions for saying that $f=g$ (on $U$)